# I rebased only a branch. Is it possible to move the others as well?

Tags: git

I was working with a repo where both origin/master and master were in the same commit. I created several branches one on top of the other. Something like

```
master--> branchDothis---> branchDothat--->branchDothistoo
```

some other member of the team advanced the master branch in the repo so after `git fetch origin master` I had master and origin/master in different commits.

So I was at branch `branchDothistoo` and I did `git rebase origin/master`

now I have

```
master---> origin/master-----> branchDothistoo
```

so the other two branches are not rebased. (but their commits are there) Is there any way to make them be in the line of commits from origin/master to branchDothistoo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Depending on if the other branches have new commits:

1. If the other branches have new commits of their own, simply check each one out and `git rebase origin/master`.
2. If the other branches don't have new commits of their own, while on a branch you wish to duplicate, you can just re-create the others with `git branch -f branchDothis`, etc. for each branch. Note you could delete them and recreate them, or use the `-f` flag which mean "force create even if it already exists". The end result is the same.

Comment: for #2 after I do this, what happen with the old `branchDothis`?

Comment: @KansaiRobot branches are just pointers to a commit, so you're basically moving the "bookmark" to point to a different commit. If the branch previously pointed to commits that were only reachable from that branch, then those commits will now be dereferenced. Your `reflog` on your machine will keep them around for a default of 90 days in case you want to get them back, and after that they will be garbage collected.